# How to align navbar-items to the right on navbar-toggler

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have my navbar working great on fullscreen and the toggler is working on smaller screens.  However, when you click on the toggler icon the navbar-items appear on the left side of the screen while the toggler-icon appears on the right.  How do I fix this so that the navbar-items appear under the navbar icon and on the right side of the screen?  I am using Bootstrap 5 for reference.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img class="navbar-logo" src="{% static 'site_base/images/image1.png' %}" alt="MagPie Logo">
  </a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#main-navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="/product1">Product 1</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">User Guides</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/company">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img
          class="navbar-logo"
          src="{% static 'site_base/images/image1.png' %}"
          alt="MagPie Logo"
        />
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark"
        style="background-color: red"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#main-navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-end" id="main-navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="/product1">Product 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">User Guides</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/company">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add `text-end` class on the `navbar-collapse` or `ul`.

Note: Try it on tablet to mobile size, I add `background-color: red` on the button, to make it visible.